# In asp.net, To access login username and id in entire application. Where can I store Login user name and id in application.?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an application in asp.net using vs2010.

In application, Admin can create different user accounts using Microsoft member registration wizard. 
Users can Login with created credential using Microsoft login control.

Now,I have to access this Logedin user's UserID and UserName in entire application's different forms.

Currently I am accessing this details by writing code in all forms by

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser();
Guid newUserId = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

So, where can i store this login user's UserID and UserName in a common place. So I can access this details from common place?

Please Help me.

Thanks,

Comment: I have stored user details in database after create the user by admin. user is login successfully with its credential after check all necessary condition. now i want to access this login user's username and userId in entire application.so i have to store this details some where in application. so i don't need to write same duplicate code in all forms. so where can I store this details in application?

Comment: what do you mean by entire form? are they not in same context? why can't you use Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey directly?

Comment: I am using this code in every forms.

Answer (score 0):

Well - that depends fully on where you persist the data for your application.

If you use a database for storage, then logically the data should belong in there, in a user table, with a connectionstring to the database in your application's configuration.

If not using databases, then you properly need some file based storage, for example XML or something you invent yourself and then have a parser which serialize/deserialize the data from files.

In both instances, you'll need to consider security and hashing/salting and make sure the data is kept secure.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a static helper class, which stores (and loads) data in HttpContext.Items for the duration of any request. So you would just need to call GetUser once per request. If even that is too much for you, you can use a Session, for example - but don't forget that sessions only live for so long, so be prepared to reload the data if it's lost due to session timeout.

The static class has to be somewhere accessible from the whole application - in a web site project, this means the App_Code folder.

Comment: Thanks Luaan.I will try with static helper class.

Comment: I have stored in public static variable and it's work for me. Thank you all.

Comment: @user3024196 : A public static variable? Are you storing it in a collection or something? Static fields are *mostly* global, even across user sessions and requests.